# How to encode URL in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-http

I'm trying to get the data from my Rest API controller using anuglarjs http GET request. However, the params that I need to send include "." symbol which caused the URL failed. I tried to encode it but it does not work. Here is what I did:

```
function getApplication($http) {
    this.getData = function(application,name) {
      return $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : http://localhost:8080/app/rest/+ 'app/' + encodeURIComponent(name)
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        return response.data;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.statusText);
      });
    }
  }
```

The name param is `app.01.com`

and the URL result I got is:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/app/rest/app/app.01.com 406 (Not Acceptable)
```

anyone know how to encode the url so I can get the data from Rest Controller?
Thanks

Comment: Pass name in as an object on the request body. {
        method : 'GET',
        url : http://localhost:8080/app/rest/+ 'app/', data: name
      }

Comment: Sounds like a bad implementation on the service side. You could try manually replacing `.` with `%2E`. If that works, the service is being too strict in its parsing rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use btoa and atob

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to decode a base-64 encoded string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The atob() method is not supported in IE9 and earlier.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Hello World!";
    var enc = window.btoa(str);
    var dec = window.atob(enc);

    var res = "Encoded String: " + enc + "<br>" + "Decoded String: " + dec;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
function getApplication($http) {
    this.getData = function(application,name) {
      return $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : http://localhost:8080/app/rest/+ 'app/' +  window.btoa(name)
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        return response.data;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.statusText);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to put the url datas into double quotes ?
        url : "http://localhost:8080/app/rest/+ 'app/' + encodeURIComponent(name)"

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that "." is an unreserved character and that "URIs that differ in the replacement of an unreserved character with its corresponding percent-encoded US-ASCII octet are equivalent". Therefore, /%2E is the same as /. , and that will get normalized away.

then you can use `localhost:8080/app/rest/app/app%2E01.com` as your urls